# href not working when i add data-toggle="dropdown"

Tags: javascript, css, menu, href, nav

when i click on main category like Kundan it's not working, thats is my code:

```html
<div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="mainNav">
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
    <li class="dropdown"><a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" role="button" aria-expanded="false">Kundan</a>
      <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu">
        <li><a href="#">Bangles</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: not working is not a question.... what is the desired behaviour?

Comment: N.B. you have tagged the Question with javascript tag but there isn't javascript in your code

Comment: You haven't set the `data-target` attribute. It does not know what to toggle.

Comment: Remove the tags javascript, css, menu, href and nav. Maybe add the tag bootstrap (if it indeed is a bootstrap toggle)

Comment: It will work if you remove data-toggle="dropdown"

Answer (score 0):

try `data-toggle="href"` instead of data-toggle="dropdown".